# Forcibly delete a branch from TFS Express 2012

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tf-cli

I have created a branch from trunk in error and want to completely destroy the branch and have so far unable to do so.

I have heard of a command called `tf destroy` but I don't seem to have this.

Does anyone know where this file is, or do I need to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question as I have found it under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE.

I was expecting to find it under the TFS Express folder as this was the logical place to look.